# How do I get my css to apply only to one page and not all pages

Tags: html, css

I'm working on learning css and I made a small dumb site, but I screwed up somehow and it's applying the border of the second page to the first page.
Here's the html of the part using the border

```
<div class="rickmorty">
    <p>The rick and morty copypasta</p>
</div>
```

Here is the html it is also applying to

```
<div class="box-1">
        <p>Test<br />Test again<br /></p>
</div>
```

And here is the css the html is applying

```
.rickmorty p{
    /*margin:50px;
    padding:20px;*/
    border: 20px #007700 solid;
    margin:50px;
    padding:10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.box-1{
    background-color: #222
}
.box-1 p{
    font-weight: 80px;
}
```

If it's something else [here is my github repository of the site](https://github.com/MarioBlaster12/MarioBlaster12.github.io)

Comment: Does `div.box-1` have `div.rickmorty` as an ancestor?

Comment: You have to give different class names. And if you don't want in second page so no need to give css link in HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to apply styles to specific pages — and make it easy to manage — simple add a class reference to the body that is unique to the page.

E.g.

```
<body class="some-page-reference">
    <p>Foo bar</p>
</body>
```

Then in your CSS:

```
body.some-page-reference p {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Although it's a matter of preference I personally find this method better than using IDs.

Alternatively, if you want to use CSS on a specific page only you can add `<style>` tags to the `<head>` and put your CSS. However, it is often desirable to keep CSS separate from the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `ID` to the elements that appear only on that unique page by doing something like:

```
<div id="unique-box-1" class="box-1">
    <p>Test<br />Test again<br /></p>
</div>
```

Then in CSS do:

```
#unique-box-1
{
   color: red; //just an example
}
```

Then the red color will be applied only to the element with that `ID`. Adjust the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of class, try to give id for an div..

The priority of id is greater than class.

Ex:

```
<div id="rickmorty">
    <p>The rick and morty copypasta</p>
</div>

<div class="box-1">
        <p>Test<br />Test again<br /></p>
</div>

#rickmorty p{
    /*margin:50px;
    padding:20px;*/
    border: 20px #007700 solid;
    margin:50px;
    padding:10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```